# Anglesharp context.openAsync() returns unrecognized character. What can I do?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, anglesharp

I am using AngleSharp to "open" a URL, change the `value` attribute of an `input` and then submit the `form`.

BUT when I get the HTML code from the URL, I get an unrecognized char in the `name` attribute of the `input` that interests me. See:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<hr>
<center>USER MENU<hr></center> 
<form method="post" name="input" enctype="text/plain"> 
<fieldset>
<legend>ENTER USER CODE</legend>
ENTER USER CODE: <input type="password" name="�00" maxlength="4">
<br>
<button type="submit" formenctype="text/plain">SEND</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see this is the only `input` in the form so I can "catch" it (to change the `value`) by other attributes of it as selectors. Like this: `[type=password]`

```
context.Active.QuerySelector(Of IHtmlInputElement)("[type=password]").SetAttribute("value", "1111")
```

So, the problem is when I submit the form, it sends the post data with wrong name and they cannot get recognized. I learned what the unrecognizable character is by opening this URL in browser, and double check it using Wireshark (to get the HEX value of the char).

Finally, the char was a greek `A` in the browser source view and as Wireshark said it was the Symbol of `C1` which is `Á` with description: `Latin capital letter A with acute` (see http://www.ascii-code.com/)

I know the man who created this web interface and he told me he used a greek `A` by fault and he cannot change it (I will explain why).

So, now that I know what the server expects I thought I could set the `name` attribute too and then send the form. But when I do it doesn't get recognized neither cause as I check in Wireshark the char is not the same char the browser sends when you submit the form. (I struggled to set the right name with no luck).

I also thought it may be some kind of encoding issue but I didn't manage to set the encoding in the `context` configuration. I set the culture to "el-GR" before I get the HTML but nothing changed.

What can I do? Do you have any suggestions?

PS. This is a low security web interface hosted by a microcontroller. The HTML cannot be changed because the device has already got a certification. Also, the interface works perfectly when used in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to create a class that `Implements` the `IEncodingProvider`  interface and then supply an instance of this class to the `Configuration` constructor via the with method.

Here is the class:

```
Private Class FixedEncodingProvider
    Implements IEncodingProvider

    Public Function Suggest(locale As String) As Encoding Implements IEncodingProvider.Suggest
        Return Encoding.GetEncoding(1253)
    End Function
End Class
```

and then use it like this:

```
Dim Config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader.With(New FixedEncodingProvider())
Dim context = BrowsingContext.[New](Config)
```

Special Thanks to the library's creator FlorianRappl for the guidance!